# Is there a filament that exhibits less deformation than PETG (when subjected to stress for a particular application)?

Tags: pla, petg, filament-choice, print-strength

I've printed a "clamp" in PETG which locks a power switch down (the "On" position). After a few days, the print is not working anymore. So I was wondering if PLA (or any filament) would be able to stay in place without deformations due to stress.

Comment: Hi, welcome to 3DPrinting.SE! Please visit [help] and take the [tour]! It's important to recognize that queries about "the best" often invite subjective responses, as they are inherently debatable and can draw opinions rather than factual answers. A more objective approach might be to reframe the question: "Is there a filament that exhibits less deformation than PETG (when subjected to stress for a particular application)?" For a comprehensive response, it would be beneficial to provide details regarding the exact clamping stress/print you're considering.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the explanations but I'm not asking which filament is better. My question is which filament is least prone to deformation if put under stress at room temperature. I'll edit my question.

Comment: This would be a design flaw rather than the wrong filament choice.

Comment: @Kilisi That sounds like the start of an answer! ld be great if the question had more details on the design.

Comment: @Kilisi yeah probably, I’ll post more details on the part when I have time. Thanks to both of you